# Haskell map function over a map (fromList) to new type

Tags: dictionary, haskell, types, casting, map-function

I'm trying to map a function over a Map (from [Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html)) instance to convert it to a new type of Map. Specifically I've got 2 types of Maps:

```
type Scope = Map.Map String AExpr
type Row = Map.Map String Value
```

A function that maps `AExpr` to `Value` ( given its first argument Scope ):

```
evalAExpr :: Scope -> AExpr -> Value
```

And an instance of type `Scope`, say `x`, for which I want to map the function `evalAExpr` over to obtain an instance of type `Row`.

According to the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html#g:12) this should be possible simply using:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
```

So in my case that would be:

```
x :: Scope
evalAExpr :: Scope -> AExpr -> Value
y = map (evalAExpr x) x :: Row
```

Since `Scope` has type `Map String AExpr`, and `Row` has type `Map String Value`.

Yet, I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> * Couldn't match type `Map.Map String AExpr' with `[AExpr]'
>   Expected type: [AExpr]
>     Actual type: Scope
> * In the second argument of `map', namely `g'
>   In the expression: map (evalAExpr g) g
>   In an equation for r': r' = map (evalAExpr g) g    | 43 |         r' = map (evalAExpr g) g
> ```

No idea why it insists on expecting a list of AExpr instead of a `Map String AExpr` ( = `Scope` ). If anyone could help me out on what I'm doing wrong and how to go about this it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong `map`.

The `map` that is in scope "by default" (which means that it comes from auto-imported module `Prelude`) is for lists:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

If you want to use one for `Map`, you need to import it. You can either shadow the list version like this:

```
import Data.Map (map)
```

Or, a better approach, import `Data.Map` as qualified, and use `map` with qualification:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

y = M.map (evalAExpr x) x
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`fmap`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.22/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Functor.html#v:fmap), which is a general version of `map` that works for any data structure that can be "mapped over". Such structures are called "functors", and `Map` is one of them:

```
y = fmap (evalAExpr x) x
```

You can also use it in operator form:

```
y = evalAExpr x <$> x
```

Operator `<$>` is just an alias for `fmap`.

Answer (score 4):

`map` only works for lists. Use `fmap` (works for all functors) or `Map.map`.